# Results per hour, even when 0 on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that gets me the number of calls for every hour. From that query I get a nice result, But when 'weekendTotals' and 'weekTotals' are 0, it leaves out that specific hour. The store is open from 8.00 till 22.00. How do I get to display the hours where both values are zero?

My SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    DATEPART(hour, CTime) AS Hour,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, CDate) IN (5, 6) THEN 1 END) AS WeekendTotals,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, CDate) NOT IN (5, 6) THEN 1 END) AS WeekTotals
FROM 
    [Example]
WHERE 
    DATEPART(YEAR, [CDate]) = @Jaar 
    AND DATEPART(MONTH, [CDate]) = @Maand
GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(hour, CTime)
ORDER BY 
    1 ,2
```

Some results:

```
+------+---------------+------------+
| Hour | WeekendTotals | WeekTotals |
+------+---------------+------------+
|    8 |             0 |          4 |
|    9 |             2 |          1 |
|   10 |             8 |          2 |
|   11 |             6 |         10 |
|   12 |             1 |          4 |
|   13 |             3 |          3 |
|   14 |             3 |          5 |
|   15 |             6 |          3 |
|   16 |             4 |          4 |
|   17 |             2 |          3 |
|   18 |             1 |          1 |
|   19 |             1 |          0 |
+------+---------------+------------+
```

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: Calendar-file LEFT JOIN aggregate ON hour.

Comment: Yep - use sqlfiddle - create table -add some data with inserts, and then add the query. then link sqlfiddle.

Comment: adding sample data for table Example. will increase interest to solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH hourset (h)
AS (SELECT TOP (22 - 8 + 1)
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY object_id) - 1 + 8
    FROM sys.all_columns)
SELECT hourset.h AS [Hour], 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, e.CDate) IN (5, 6) THEN 1 END) AS WeekendTotals,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, e.CDate) NOT IN (5, 6) THEN 1 END) AS WeekTotals
FROM hourset 
LEFT JOIN [Example] e ON hourset.h = DATEPART(HOUR, e.cTime)
WHERE 
    e.cTime IS NULL or
    (DATEPART(YEAR, [CDate]) = @Jaar 
    AND DATEPART(MONTH, [CDate]) = @Maand)
GROUP BY hourset.h
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

Comment: This gave me exact the same result as my results above. But your suggestion gave me an idea. I'm using Stimulsoft, so I made an empty table with the beginning of your query.

`SELECT TOP (22 - 8 + 1)
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY object_id) - 1 + 8
    FROM sys.all_columns;`

And then linked those to together in Stimulsoft. Thanks!